# Using "if #available(iOS 15, *)" within SwiftUI View crashes the app

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I'm trying to keep my code for removing list separators in iOS 14 while adopting the new `.listRowSeparatorVisibility` for iOS 15 onward.

```
extension View {
  func listRowModifier(color: Color) -> some View {
    let view = self
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
      .background(color)
    
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
      return AnyView(
        view
          .listRowSeparatorVisibility(.hidden)
          .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
      )
    } else {
      return AnyView(
        view
          .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: -1, leading: 0, bottom: -1, trailing: 0))
      )
    }
  }
}
```

This crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

```
#0  0x0000000186e84214 in swift_getOpaqueTypeMetadata ()
#1  0x0000000100dc2b50 in View.listRowModifier(color:) ()
```

Crashes on this line in the View:

```
List {
  Spacer().frame(height: headerHeight + Theme.unit(2)).listRowModifier()
  ...
}
```

Other things I've tried:

1. Using @ViewBuilder instead, also crashes
2. Doing the if else directly in the View instead of using an extension, also crashes

** **Update** **

When the views returned within the `if` and `else` block are identical, it works. If not, it crashes. I'm not sure how that's useful consider the whole point of this is that the views are different because one has a feature that the other doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

The issue was that `.listRowSeparatorVisibility` was deprecated in iOS 15. I changed it to `.listRowSeparator` and it stopped crashing.

That was not clear at all, but I'll leave this here in case anyone else runs into this issue.